# Flash background color of SumoSelect on update

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, animation, sumoselect.js

I was using the normal HTML 'select' element on my page, and based on user selections, some filtering would happen for other select elements. When those other select elements would update, I would flash the backgroundColor with jQueryUI to alert the user that something happened.

```
$(select_element)
            .animate({backgroundColor: "#bdedff"}, 200)
            .delay(350)
            .animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 200);
```

The above would change the `backgroundColor` of the element to blue, then back to white.

Now that I am using [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/), this does not seem to be working. I never see the blue (first color in the animation), but the background (which defaults to gray) is turned white (second color in the animation). If I reverse the colors in the above example, the element ends up blue (as would be expected). But why is the first color not seen?

(I don't have enough reputation to add a 'sumoselect' tag)